# What is the optimal strategy when playing `head or tail` per team

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving, game-theory

**Introduction**

Once a week, we are playing `head or tail` in my favorite bar.

There are $N$ people in the room and each person is guessing whether `head` or `tail` will come up to the next toss. If you lose you sit down. If you win you remain standing. The last person to be standing brings the victory to its team.

The are $n$ different teams and the number of members in each team is $[x_1, x_2, ...,x_{n-1}, x_n]$ such that $\sum_i^n x_i = N$. Let's call my team "team 1". There are therefore $x_1$ members in my team.

**Strategy**

A friend of mine came with the strategy that at each toss, half of the team is playing `head`, while the other half is playing `tail`.

**Question**

If everybody is playing randomly, our probability of winning is $\frac{x}{N}$.

- Does my friend's strategy affect this probability?
- What would be the optimal strategy?
- Is the best strategy different depending on what strategy the other teams are playing (and depending the number of individuals in each team)?

Comment: Your friend's strategy is optimal and dominates random play. Random play yields $\frac x N$ only if other groups play randomly. If they don't, you'll get less.

Comment: The intuition is that you want your "worse" case to be as good as possible which yields even (or almost) split. Expected number of survivors after $n$ plays is $x/2^n$, so the more concentrated you are around the mean, the higher $P(X>0)$ (what you care about) is. Random choice leads to higher variance.

Comment: You need to specify what happens if *everyone* guesses wrong on the final round -- i.e., does everyone lose, or is it a "partial" win for each team (and if so, how is it apportioned)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split your team of $x$ into $t$ tails and $h$ heads, you'll get the average of the game values with $t$ and $h$ people left. If the game value is concave with respect to the number of people on your team, this average is optimal for an even split $t=\lfloor\frac x2\rfloor$, $h=\lceil\frac x2\rceil$. My guess would be that this will always be the case, independent of the other teams' strategies, but the details of proving that seem messy.

Let's look at the game with two teams to get a feel for things. We can derive the game values $v(x_1,x_2)$ starting from the initial values $v(x_1,0)=1$ for $x_1\gt0$ and $v(0,x_2)=0$ for $x_2\gt0$. You didn't specify $v(0,0)$; I'll take it to be $\frac12$ (a split prize).

Here's a table of game values if both teams always split, for $x_1,x_2\le4$ (with $x_1$ downward and $x_2$ to the right):

\begin{array}{c|cc}
&0&1&2&3&4\\\hline
0&\frac12&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&\frac12&\frac14&\frac3{16}&\frac18\\
2&1&\frac34&\frac12&\frac38&\frac14\\
3&1&\frac{13}{16}&\frac58&\frac12&\frac38\\
4&1&\frac78&\frac34&\frac58&\frac12\\
\end{array}

The value is concave in $x_1$ (and accordingly convex in $x_2$), so splitting is indeed optimal. We can also derive the game values if your team splits while the other plays randomly:

\begin{array}{c|cc}
&0&1&2&3&4\\\hline
0&\frac12&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&\frac12&\frac5{14}&\frac{19}{70}&\frac{471}{2170}\\
2&1&\frac34&\frac{33}{56}&\frac{269}{560}&\frac{13987}{34720}\\
3&1&\frac{13}{16}&\frac{305}{448}&\frac{5231}{8960}&\frac{566131}{1111040}\\
4&1&\frac78&\frac{173}{224}&\frac{3079}{4480}&\frac{342339}{555520}\\
\end{array}

Here, too the value is concave in your team count, so your split play is optimal also against random play. Here's a direct comparison with approximate decimal values (split play first):

\begin{array}{c|cc}
&0&1&2&3&4\\\hline
0&0.500&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&0.500&0.250/0.357&0.188/0.271&0.125/0.217\\
2&1&0.750&0.500/0.589&0.375/0.480&0.250/0.403\\
3&1&0.813&0.625/0.681&0.500/0.584&0.375/0.510\\
4&1&0.875&0.750/0.772&0.625/0.687&0.500/0.616\\
\end{array}

For completeness, here are the game values for random play by both teams:

\begin{array}{c|cc}
&0&1&2&3&4\\\hline
0&0.500&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&0.500&0.357&0.271&0.217\\
2&1&0.643&0.500&0.407&0.343\\
3&1&0.729&0.593&0.500&0.433\\
4&1&0.783&0.657&0.567&0.500\\
\end{array}

The values are much closer to $\frac12$ than for optimal play by both teams, since random play is worse at taking advantage of superior numbers.

[Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/e856617e2d3581e1de76) I used to compute the game values.

Comment: I appreciate the work +1 :) I understand you simulated the values rather than calculating them.

Comment: To help me build my intuition could you please tell more about 1) what is meant by this statement `The value is concave in x1`,  2) how you came about this statement (if not just by looking at the results of your simulation) and 3) how does it result into `so splitting is indeed optimal`.

Comment: @Remi.b: What made you think I simulated the values rather than calculating them? Would be rather crazy of me to write fractions with $6$-digit denominators if these were just approximate simulations :-) No, I linked to the code that does the computations; these are the exact numbers. (For random play I didn't put the exact fractions in a table, but the code produces them.)

Comment: @Remi.b: About your questions: 1) see [Concave function at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function)  2) because we're dealing with averages of function values further apart or closer together, and that's sort of what convexity and concavity is about; 3) "so splitting is indeed optimal" because if the function is concave, the average of two function values at arguments with a given sum is maximal in the symmetric case where both arguments are half the sum.